# How can i format my hard drive to get rid of windows?

Tags: hard-drive

I have downloaded ubuntu 12.04 and was hoping that when i booted off of my flash drive it would come up like it used to in 9.04 and would ask if you wanted to format your hard drive. But It didn't do it. How do i get it to let me format before installing ubuntu?

Comment: I installed directly over Windows- just load up the installer and choose to replace the current operating system and the disk will be formatted in ext4 and Ubuntu installed.

Answer (score 1):

I just did this exact thing literally yesterday.

Make sure everything that you need off of the computer is backed up, you really are going to wipe it clean!(well sort of.. )

Reboot your computer off of the flash drive just as you are used to, and go ahead and click install Ubuntu. Eventually you will come to a screen with options such as:

1. Install alongside existing operating system(s)
2. Erase Disk and Install Ubuntu *** This is the one you want ***
3. Other Options(advanced)

Click the option that says erase disk and install Ubuntu, and follow the steps. 
This will format your hard drive, and then install Ubuntu on the clean drive.

Hope this helps, Good luck!

Comment: But "Erase Disk and Install Ubuntu" option does not provide swap partition(which is useful)

Comment: @zuberuber Erase Disk and Install Ubuntu creates two partitions, / and swap. It does not create a /home partition though.